# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE using file-uploader safari and mac

Tags: fine-uploader

My clients report this error from time to time.  They receive new::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and the upload retries the maximum number, then fails. Most recent occurrence was on OSX Maverick, Chrome.  It happens on Safari as well.

The problem is not widespread, it occurs on a relatively small % of clients.

```
Fine Uploader 5.1.3
s3.jquery.fine-uploader.js:3878
new::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
s3.jquery.fine-uploader.js:29
POST request for 0 has failed - response code 0
Received an empty or invalid response from the server!
```

Here is a console screenshot

[image]

Comment: Here is the console log screenshot.    https://s3.amazonaws.com/txs_static/console.png

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your server or network. The browser complains the the preflight request is being returned with a completely empty response. This is not an issue with Fine Uploader. You'll need to examine logs on your signature server, or perhaps there are some network issues on your end or your client's end.

Comment: Tomcat on EC2.   The tomcat logs are clean.  How would I determine if its a network issue?

Comment: You'll have to inspect network traffic on both ends.